# Intercept jersey endpoint methods

Tags: java, rest, jersey, endpoint

i am using jersey to build a REST webservice.
I created a class, implementing the ContainerRequestFilter interface to determine whether a user is logged in or not. Now I 'd like to discard each request that is submitted if user == null. How can this be achieved? I don't want to put a

```
if (user != null ) {
 ...
} else {
 return //401
}
```

in each action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

throw WebApplicationException:

```
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    if (user != null ) {
           //...
        } else {
            throw new WebApplicationException(401);
        }
    return request;
}
```